# Iterate over rows/checkboxes in a RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, foreach, telerik, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid with a GridTemplateColumn that contains a checkbox, as follows:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="MINE" UniqueName="MyTemplateColumn">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox id="MyCheckBox" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to set the box to be "checked" based on a value read from the database. I could handle the ItemDataBound event and read the database when each row is bound, but that results in *n* lookups. Instead, I want to handle DataBound, and then set all the values at once. So, in that method, I want code like this:

```
// read all values from database first, then...
foreach(var chkbox in MyRadGrid.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("MyTemplateColumn").FindControl("MyCheckBox")) {
    chkbox.Checked = oneValue;
}
```

That doesn't work, because FindControl isn't a method of GridColumn, and it won't generate an iterable list of the checkboxes. What is the correct way to iterate through the checkboxes in the template column? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Telerik got back to me on their forums with the answer, as follows:

```
foreach (GridDataItem item in MyRadGrid.MasterTableView.Items) 
{ 
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
  // Set the value here
}
```

Hope this is useful for someone!

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue.. this was how I did it..

'Created a local hashtable to use now and otherwise

```
Private _GroupMembers As New Hashtable
```

'Loaded it up on page load
    Private Function GetMembers() As Boolean

```
    Try

        Dim da As New DataAccess
        Dim ht As New Hashtable
        Dim i As Int16 = 0

        ht.Add("CAC", Session("cac"))
        ht.Add("GroupID", _GroupID)
        If da.GetData("rap_spGetGroupMemberList", ht) = True Then
            If da.SQLDataRows.HasRows Then
                While da.SQLDataRows.Read()
                    i = i + 1
                    _GroupMembers.Add(i, da.SQLDataRows("UserID"))
                End While
            End If
            da.SQLDataRows.Dispose()
        End If

        da = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

'Check for contains
    Protected Sub RadGrid2_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid2.ItemDataBound

```
    Try

        If e.Item.IsDataBound Then
            If Not e.Item.DataItem("UserID") Is Nothing Then
                If Not IsDBNull(e.Item.DataItem("UserID")) Then
                    Dim UserID As Long = e.Item.DataItem("UserID")
                    If _GroupMembers.ContainsValue(UserID) Then
                        e.Item.Selected = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```